# Assembly, easy code, Segmentation fault why

Tags: assembly, x86

I just wrote my first assembly code, tried to copy an easy c++ operation.
The values are good, but the run is ending with segmentation fault. Why?

```
;int x = 10;
;int y = 20;
;x += y;
;cout<<x<<"\n";


;*********************
global main
extern readln
extern println

section .data
X dd 10
Y dd 20

section .txt

main:
; second arg to eax
mov eax, [Y]

push eax

; first arg to eax
mov eax, [X]

pop ebx
add eax, ebx

push eax
call println
add esp, 4
```

Comment: What is the definition of `println`?

Comment: Because you didn't add an ending :)  Try using a `ret`.

Comment: it's a simple c printing:
void println( unsigned var )
{
 fprintf( stdout, "%u\n", var );
}

Comment: No self-respecting C compiler uses stdcall ;)

Comment: thank you, @Jester, it was helped :)